# What is the algorithm called for the increase in how many times you will roll successfully as you decrease the chances for failure

Tags: probability, dice

Let's say you have a 20 sided dice and every side is considered bad, but each time you roll a bad side it will no longer be bad for future rolls. 
I am looking for the mathmatical term for the scale of increase on the expected amount of times you will be able to roll success as bad sides are removed

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Can you answer the same question explicitly for a $2$ sided die?  (i.e. a coin)

Comment: Oh, are you just asking "if there are $n$ good sides and $m$ bad sides, what's the expected number of throws it will take until I see a bad one?"  If so, then the probability that a given throw is bad is $\frac m{m+n}$ and the expected time is just the reciprocal, $\frac {m+n}m$.

Comment: If I am interpreting your question correctly (of which I am not at all sure), then you are asking about the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the distribution of the count for rolls of a twenty sided dice until *some* number appears a second time.   Who knows what this is called, but anyway:

Let $X$ denote this random variable.   The event $\{X=k\}$ is that of showing some permutation of $(k-1)$ distinct numbers, followed by a repetition of one of these.   There can be between at least $2$ and at most $21$ rolls before some number is encountered a second time.   Thus:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=k) ~=~& \left(\frac {{^{20}{\rm P}_{k-1}}}{20^{k-1}}\right)\dfrac{(k-1)}{20}~\mathbf 1_{k\in\{2,..,21\}}
\\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{20!~(k-1)}{(21-k)!~20^k}~\mathbf 1_{k\in\{2,..,21\}}
\\[3ex] \mathsf E(X)~=~&\dfrac{4027894135040576041}{640000000000000000} ~~\approx~~6.{\small 2\tiny 9}\end{align}$$